# Is it possible to create a S3 Bucket in us-east-1 using AWS Python Boto3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

[Documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-example-creating-buckets.html)

```py
import logging
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError


def create_bucket(bucket_name, region=None):
    try:
        if region is None:
            s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
            s3_client.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name)
        else:
            s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name=region)
            location = {'LocationConstraint': region}
            s3_client.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name,
                                    CreateBucketConfiguration=location)
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return False
    return True
```

Testing:

`create_bucket('test', 'us-west-2')` Works as expected -> Please select a different name and try again

`create_bucket('test')` The unspecified location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent to.

`create_bucket('test', 'us-east-1')` The us-east-1 location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent to.

What did I miss?

Comment: The middle test is strange because it looks like its hitting your `else:` when it shouldn't The last one is expected as you are trying to create in a different region than you are sending the API request to.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but what region specific endpoint was the request sent to, meaning what's the default region in your AWS CLI setup?

Comment: @Erwin region = us-east-1 in ~/.aws/config

Comment: Also may be worth [enabling boto3 debug logging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30249685/271415).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This creates a bucket in `us-east-1`:

```py
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='us-east-1')
s3_client.create_bucket(Bucket='unique-name-here')
```

Comment: yes, it is. Thank you John

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the `error message`.

Obviously, the bucket with the name `test` is already taken, but for some reason, instead of saying `Please select a different name and try again`, we see a message that misleads us.

So the solution is simple - `use a unique name for the bucket`.

I hope AWS will fix the error message ASAP but it's not a blocker for us anyway